# Python Pandas: Partition size is less than overlapping window size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, swifter

I am trying to compute the slope of a time series using `Pandas` with `Switfer` by doing this.

My code:

```
import os.path
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

import numpy as np
import pandas_ta
from scipy.stats import linregress

import pandas as pd
import swifter

FILE_PATH = "Data"


def get_files_ohlc(path: str):
    return [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]


def get_slope(array):
    y = np.array(array)
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
    return slope


def add_slop_indicator(ohlc: pd.DataFrame, ind: str, candles_back: int):
    ohlc[f'slope_{val}_{days}'] = ohlc[ind].swifter.rolling(window=candles_back, min_periods=candles_back).apply(
        get_slope, raw=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = get_files_ohlc(FILE_PATH)
    dicts = {}

    for file in files:
        name_pair = file.split("_")[0]
        dicts[name_pair] = pd.read_json(os.path.join(FILE_PATH, file))
        dicts[name_pair].rename({0: 'date',
                                 1: 'open',
                                 2: 'high',
                                 3: 'low',
                                 4: 'close',
                                 5: 'volume'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
        dicts[name_pair]['date'] = dicts[name_pair]['date'].values.astype(dtype='datetime64[ms]')
        for val in range(20, 100):
            dicts[name_pair].ta.ema(length=val, append=True)

        print(f"END_{name_pair}")
        for val in range(20, 100):
            for days in range(5, 100):
                add_slop_indicator(dicts[name_pair], f"EMA_{val}", days)
        print(f"DONE {name_pair}")
```

But after running it for a while I will get this error message and the program will stop running.

Error:

```
dask.multiprocessing.NotImplementedError: Partition size is less than overlapping window size. Try using ``df.repartition`` to increase the partition size.
```

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my code to make it a simple workable example.

`pandas_ta` (is used for `dicts[name_pair].ta`) -> is [this](https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta) library which is going to allow me to use EMA (which is just an indicator)

All the code can be found in this [repository](https://github.com/Vildnex/Crypto_15m_data) that I've created for this question. If you will run the code from `test.py` it will output that error message that I am asking about.

Hope that this would help, otherwise please let me know what would needs to be clarified.

My traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/test.py", line 51, in <module>
    add_slop_indicator(dicts[name_pair], f"EMA_{val}", days)
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/test.py", line 27, in add_slop_indicator
    ohlc[f'slope_{val}_{days}'] = ohlc[ind].swifter.rolling(window=candles_back, min_periods=candles_back).apply(
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/swifter/swifter.py", line 521, in apply
    return self._dask_apply(func, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/swifter/swifter.py", line 562, in _dask_apply
    dd.from_pandas(self._comparison_pd, npartitions=self._npartitions)
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 292, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 575, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py", line 220, in get
    result = get_async(
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 508, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py", line 110, in reraise
    raise exc
dask.multiprocessing.NotImplementedError: Partition size is less than overlapping window size. Try using ``df.repartition`` to increase the partition size.

Traceback
---------
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 221, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/vlad/Crypto_15m_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/rolling.py", line 29, in overlap_chunk
    raise NotImplementedError(msg)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please include a full [mre] including the definition of `dataframe`. You don’t even specify what dataframe is, but it seems it’s a dask.dataframe?

Comment: And what is dataframe.ta?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I did update my question with all the needed details and I've also created a small repository with a workable example. Hope that it would help to make my problem clear. Let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: got it thanks for the edits! one more nitpick - is that a warning message and then your program crashes elsewhere or is that just the last line of a [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback)? Either way, please always post the full traceback when asking about errors. But since you're not initializing a dask.dataframe anywhere I assume this is either a bug in pandas_ta or swifter, or you're calling one of them incorrectly. I don't have any experience with those packages - sorry. This is probably a q for the pandas_ta or swifter user groups.

Comment: I see... ok I will post over there then, thx for you help :)

Comment: for sure - and FWIW I think this is a totally fair SO question and with the added info it's enough for us to go on, but I just think you might have more luck posting directly to swifter because it seems like it's an issue with the way it is using dask.dataframe under the hood. good luck!